# Button doesn't load correctly

Tags: javascript, popup, blogger, tumblr

I'm using a JS button for Tumblr, which I've customised to [my blog](http://easytestcore.blogspot.com.au/)'s variables. The button loads a pop-up window, but instead of appearing under each individual post, they're all grouped together. Also, it's outputting: `&quot;` into the Tumblr share screen title instead of actual quotes.

How can I centre the pop-up window on being clicked?

```
<script src='http://platform.tumblr.com/v1/share.js'/>

<span id='tumblr_button_abc123'></span>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var strPostUrl = "<data:post.url/>";
var strPostTitle = '<data:post.title/>';
var tumblr_link_url = strPostUrl.replace("http://","");
var tumblr_link_name = strPostTitle.replace(/"/g, '"');
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var tumblr_button = document.createElement("a");
tumblr_button.setAttribute("href", "http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=" + encodeURIComponent(tumblr_link_url) + "&name=" + encodeURIComponent(tumblr_link_name));
tumblr_button.setAttribute("title", "Share on Tumblr");
tumblr_button.setAttribute("style", "display:inline-block; text-indent:-9999px; overflow:hidden; width:81px; height:20px; background:url('http://platform.tumblr.com/v1/share_1.png') top left no-repeat transparent;");
tumblr_button.innerHTML = "Share on Tumblr";
document.getElementById("tumblr_button_abc123").appendChild(tumblr_button);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple `span` with the id `tumblr_button_abc123`, so when you add a button to this id, only the first `span` get the buttons

Comment: I understand, but how can I fix that?